# Elasticsearch Not Returning Expected Results For Singular vs Plural

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently having an issue with being unable to return hits for with a particular search term, and it's a bit perplexing to me:

Term: `navy flower`

The query would up looking like:

`(name: "navy flower"~5 OR sku: "navy flower"~10 OR description: "navy flower"~5)`

No hits.

If I change the term to: `navy flowers`

I get 3 hits with it:

[image: Hit Result]

The mappings I currently have setup on the index are as follows:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "active": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "sku": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "upc": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm must be missing something obvious for the match to not be working on the singular vs plural form of the word.

Comment: can you please share some sample data and your expected search results ? And please share the exact search query which you are using

Answer (score 0):

As per your index mapping, you have not specified any analyzer that means elastic search by default use [standard analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) and standard analyzer doesn't do stemming as by default it have only 2 token filter:

1. Lower Case Token Filter
2. Stop Token Filter (by default disabled)

For supporting your use case, you required [Stemmer token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html) with the analyzer. So you can create a custom analyzer and configured to the required field:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "active": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "sku": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "upc": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After this you can search with below query:

```
GET test/_search?q=(name:"navy flower"~5 OR sku: "navy flower"~10 OR description: "navy flower"~5)
```